# SQL Overlap with filter inside array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Previously i try to use overlap to find data where data has any of values in array. I use postgres

SQL statement was:

```
SELECT *,
ARRAY_AGG("reserve"."state_id" ) AS "states" 
FROM "orders_order"
JOIN "reserve" ON ("order"."id" = "reserve"."order_id")
GROUP BY "order"."id"
HAVING (ARRAY_AGG("reserve"."state_id" )&& array['test', 'test_new']::varchar(255)[])
```

For example if my states where like below:

```
{'test', 'new_test' }
```

It gives me all reserves if states `test` was in array

Now i need receive states if only `['test']` in array

Expected output must be empty in above mentioned example

Some examples to clarify:

```
1. {'test', 'new_test' } -> false
2. {'test', 'test' } -> true
3. {'test'} -> true
```

How can i achieve this. What needs to add to my SQL statement?

Comment: SQL does not support arrays in general.  Tag with the database you areusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `@>` (contains operator):

```
SELECT 
 array['test'] @> array['test','new_test'], --false
 array['test'] @> array['test','test'],     --true
 array['test'] @> array['test'];            --true

 ?column? | ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------+----------
 f        | t        | t
```